# Searching for a preference in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search 3.6.2 and I want to sort specific documents to the front. For that  reason, I have written a custom comparator-Source, but somehow it doesn't seem to work.

I want documents, that have these preferred values in them to be sorted to the front.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class PreferenceFieldComparatorSource<T> extends FieldComparatorSource {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8959374194451783596L;

    private final List<?> preferred;
    private final Class<?> clazz;
    private final StringBridge stringBridge;

    @SafeVarargs
    public PreferenceFieldComparatorSource(Class<T> clazz,
            StringBridge stringBridge, T... preferred) {
        this(clazz, stringBridge, Arrays.asList(preferred));
    }

    public PreferenceFieldComparatorSource(Class<T> clazz,
            StringBridge stringBridge, List<T> preferred) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.stringBridge = stringBridge;
        this.preferred = preferred;
    }

    @Override
    public FieldComparator<String> newComparator(final String fieldName,
            int numHits, int sortPos, final boolean reversed)
            throws IOException {
        return new FieldComparator<String>() {

            private String[] values;
            private String bottom;
            private String[] currentReaderValues;

            @Override
            public int compare(int slot1, int slot2) {
                return this.compare(this.values[slot1], this.values[slot2]);
            }

            @Override
            public int compareBottom(int doc) throws IOException {
                return this.compare(this.bottom, this.currentReaderValues[doc]);
            }

            @Override
            public void copy(int slot, int doc) throws IOException {
                this.values[slot] = this.currentReaderValues[doc];
            }

            @Override
            public void setBottom(int slot) {
                this.bottom = this.values[slot];
            }

            @Override
            public void setNextReader(IndexReader reader, int docBase)
                    throws IOException {
                System.out.println("fieldName: " + fieldName);

                this.currentReaderValues = new String[reader.maxDoc()];
                this.values = new String[reader.maxDoc()];
                for (int i = 0; i < currentReaderValues.length; ++i) {
                    try {
                        this.currentReaderValues[i] = reader.document(docBase)
                                .get(fieldName);
                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.stringBridge
                                        + " doesn't convert strings into "
                                        + PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.clazz);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String value(int slot) {
                return this.values[slot];
            }

            private int compare(Object first, Object second) {
                // if none of the given values is in the preferred lists
                // the index is -1 but the compare function will still work
                // correctly
                // and will only move the preferred ones.
                int firstIndex = PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.preferred
                        .indexOf(PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.stringBridge
                                .objectToString(first));
                int secondIndex = PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.preferred
                        .indexOf(PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.stringBridge
                                .objectToString(second));
                int result = Integer.compare(firstIndex, secondIndex);
                if (reversed) {
                    result *= -1;
                }
                return result;
            }

        };
    }

}
```

The compare method doesn't seem to get called. What am I doing wrong in this class for that to be the case?

EDIT:

for clarification of a statement in the comments:

```
         @Override
         protected boolean lessThan(final Entry hitA, final Entry hitB) {

             assert hitA != hitB;
             assert hitA.slot != hitB.slot;

             int numComparators = comparators.length;
             for (int i = 0; i < numComparators; ++i) {
                 final int c = reverseMul[i] * comparators[i].compare(hitA.slot,
             hitB.slot);
             if (c != 0) {
             // Short circuit
             return c > 0;
             }
         }

         // avoid random sort order that could lead to duplicates (bug
         #31241):
         return hitA.doc > hitB.doc;
        }
```

Comment: does someone have an idea?

Comment: How would you expect the FieldComparatorSource implementation to be picked up? I am not quite sure what you try to do so. Why do you not just boost the preferred values at index or search time? This should get them to the top as well.

Comment: Do you try to do something like: Sort sort = new Sort( new SortField( "foo", new PreferenceFieldComparatorSource() ) ); query.setSort( sort );? That should work.

Comment: Yes I am doing the query.setSort(...) stuff. And I have already written a functioning ComparatorSource that sorts into a random order (it's application specific to our project). After the random sort has taken place I want to sort specific documents to the front (again application specific) and I don't think that can be done via boosts (or at least that seems too unreliable for me).

Comment: the setNextReader(...) method is getting called, so is the copy method, but the compare stuff is never getting called, but I can't make out, why...

Comment: That's odd. Can you provide a full example with entities, search query, etc?

Comment: i got it. Either i misread the documentation of the Sort class or it's wrong. It clearly states that it sorts in succession but it doesn't in the sense like sorting a java list 3 times in succession. Instead it behaves more like the inverse of that. (I added that to the question).

Comment: and furthermore my comparator was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it. Either i misread the documentation of the Sort class or it's wrong. It clearly states that it sorts in succession but it doesn't in the sense like sorting a java list 3 times in succession. Instead it behaves more like the inverse of that.

from the Hibernate-Search sourcecode:

```
     @Override
     protected boolean lessThan(final Entry hitA, final Entry hitB) {

         assert hitA != hitB;
         assert hitA.slot != hitB.slot;

         int numComparators = comparators.length;
         for (int i = 0; i < numComparators; ++i) {
             final int c = reverseMul[i] * comparators[i].compare(hitA.slot,
         hitB.slot);
         if (c != 0) {
         // Short circuit
         return c > 0;
         }
     }

     // avoid random sort order that could lead to duplicates (bug
     #31241):
     return hitA.doc > hitB.doc;
    }
```

and furthermore my comparator was wrong:

```
public class PreferenceFieldComparatorSource<T> extends FieldComparatorSource {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8959374194451783596L;

    private final List<?> preferred;
    private final Class<?> clazz;
    private final TwoWayStringBridge stringBridge;

    @SafeVarargs
    public PreferenceFieldComparatorSource(Class<T> clazz,
            TwoWayStringBridge stringBridge, T... preferred) {
        this(clazz, stringBridge, Arrays.asList(preferred));
    }

    public PreferenceFieldComparatorSource(Class<T> clazz,
            TwoWayStringBridge stringBridge, List<T> preferred) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.stringBridge = stringBridge;
        this.preferred = preferred;
    }

    @Override
    public FieldComparator<String> newComparator(final String fieldName,
            int numHits, int sortPos, final boolean reversed)
            throws IOException {
        return new FieldComparator<String>() {

            private String[] values;
            private String bottom;
            private String[] currentReaderValues;

            @Override
            public int compare(int slot1, int slot2) {
                return this.compare(this.values[slot1], this.values[slot2]);
            }

            @Override
            public int compareBottom(int doc) throws IOException {
                return this.compare(this.bottom, this.currentReaderValues[doc]);
            }

            @Override
            public void copy(int slot, int doc) throws IOException {
                this.values[slot] = this.currentReaderValues[doc];
            }

            @Override
            public void setBottom(int slot) {
                this.bottom = this.values[slot];
            }

            @Override
            public void setNextReader(IndexReader reader, int docBase)
                    throws IOException {                
                this.currentReaderValues = new String[reader.maxDoc()];
                this.values = new String[reader.maxDoc()];
                for (int i = 0; i < currentReaderValues.length; ++i) {
                    try {
                        this.currentReaderValues[i] = reader.document(i)
                                .get(fieldName);
                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.stringBridge
                                        + " doesn't convert strings into "
                                        + PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.clazz);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String value(int slot) {
                return this.values[slot];
            }

            private int compare(Object first, Object second) {
                int firstIndex = PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.preferred
                        .indexOf(PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.stringBridge
                                .stringToObject((String) first));
                int secondIndex = PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.preferred
                        .indexOf(PreferenceFieldComparatorSource.this.stringBridge
                                .stringToObject((String) second));
                int result;
                if(firstIndex == -1 || secondIndex == -1) {
                    if(firstIndex == secondIndex) {
                        result = 0;
                    } else if(firstIndex == -1) {
                        result = 1;
                    } else {
                        result = -1;
                    }
                } else {
                    result = Integer.compare(firstIndex, secondIndex);
                }
                if (reversed) {
                    result *= -1;
                }
                return result;
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what confused you regarding the documentation of the Sort class, but if you want to propose a patch to improve the wording of it I'd be happy to include it in the project.

Comment: Here is my approach for the documentation :):

Sorts in succession by the criteria in each SortField.
<br>
"in succession" doesn't mean that the whole resultsset is sorted 
more than once like calling sort multiple times on a regular Java Collection.
<br>
Instead it means that SortFields with a lower index get consulted first and if they (the SortFields) can determine whether one Document comes before another, no other SortFields are consulted. However, if they return that the compared Documents are equal, SortFields with a lower index are consulted to determine the sorting.

Comment: better :)? It would be an honor if that got added to the HibernateSearch repo. btw: nice job on the api in general :). Nearly no day goes by while developing that I don't praise the awesomemess of the  api.

Comment: Thanks! but I realize now that you're referring to org.apache.lucene.search.Sort : that is maintained in a different repository by the Lucene team, we can try proposing a change but it's going to be a more complex process.

Comment: yup. I already thought, this might be a bit of a concern. But I think it would be worth it. Should I try to submit it?